# Type mismatch: inferred type is RewardItem? but RewardItem was expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native, admob, react-native-google-mobile-ads

```
e: /node_modules/react-native-google-mobile-ads/android/src/main/java/io/invertase/googlemobileads/ReactNativeGoogleMobileAdsAdHelper.kt: (76, 33): Type mismatch: inferred type is RewardItem? but RewardItem was expected
```

someone know how fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your variable can be `undefined`. You can see that with the `?` at the end of `RewardItem?`. You must probably deal with the case before calling admob method.